# Are LINQ-to-SQL Stored Procedures cached?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, datacontext

I wrote a couple stored procedures on the database I am using for reporting. Then I used LINQ-to-SQL to pull the stored procedures into a DBML file and create the actual C# functions. The data extract is served up via a WCF service.

The dilemma I am having now is if I run the stored procedure from the function, then upload new game stats, then run the stored procedure again (disposing the DataContext inbetween uses) I am getting the results set as if the new game stats hadn't been uploaded. However, if I go run the stored procedure directly against the database I get the correct results set.

To me this indicates a few possibilities which I'm not sure how to handle:

1. The service is somehow caching the stored procedures results which seems odd give I am disposing the DataContext
2. Somehow the stored procedure is ignoring the state of the rest of the DataContext
3. Something else entirely

I'm thinking DataContext.Refresh() will solve the problem but if I can avoid the performance hit from that I'd like to, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if the results were cached (query plans are cached), this would be a common problem, and a search would presumably turn up a lot of hits....I would suggest showing your clear, concise, short, compilable example code..

Comment: @MitchWheat that's going to require quite a bit of cleansing, but I'll see if I can make it happen tonight. Thanks for the input.

Comment: no they are not cached, not sure if you are caching results, in statics fields, or if you are caching the whole page if it is a web app

Comment: @OscarCabrero updated the main post, but to answer your questions its a WCF service that is basically acting as an API.